# Starting an Activity from a ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-activity, android-contentprovider

I have a content provider which serves data from a user's account. Should the user not be logged in, I would like to show a login dialog upon an application requesting data from the content provider. Is it possible? Or am I going about this all wrong? I suppose an alternative solution would be to throw an exception or return error-indicating data from the content provider, and let the application handle it, but I feel the first solution would be the best because the application doesn't have to worry about the user being logged in or the user interface required for login.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Provider : ContentProvider() {
    override fun onCreate() = true

    override fun query(
        uri: Uri,
        projection: Array<String>,
        selection: String?,
        selectionArgs: Array<String>?,
        sortOrder: String?
    ): Cursor? {
        context.startActivity(Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
            .apply { flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK })
        return null
    }

    override fun getType(uri: Uri) = null

    override fun insert(uri: Uri, values: ContentValues) = null

    override fun delete(uri: Uri, selection: String, selectionArgs: Array<String>) = 0

    override fun update(
        uri: Uri,
        values: ContentValues?,
        selection: String?,
        selectionArgs: Array<String>?
    ) = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think services.  However it is not usually advised to start activities from services and therefore probably not content providers either.  Most confusing part of your question however is "upon an application requesting data from the content provider"  Is this content provider available to multiple android apps?

Comment: The content provider isn't available to other apps right now, but I don't see why it shouldn't be in the future. It could be of some use. Besides, isn't that one of the main reasons to use a content provider? To provide content to other applications? Although, I guess if any app uses the content provider it will be one of our own.

Comment: The only way I have seen this done is to create an remote service and deploy that with the content provider inside. A remote service can be bound to by several apps. Then you would be able to provide each application that connected to your remote service with some type of call back or events to inform it of the changes.

Comment: So if you use a remote service you can use that as a common api with callbacks for several apps.  A local service would not work.

Comment: Basically Activities and services can communicate because they subclass context.  Any other class can also communicate if it has a refernce to a valid context. So if you create your content provider and provide it a refernce to a valid context it too can send or broadcast intents which can be picked up in different parts of your application.  I think a broadcast might be what you are looking for if its just one application.

Comment: btw, sticky broadcasts will linger so that when you check last sticky broadcast on say a resume of an activity you can be informed of changes.

Comment: Most anything can register to be a broadcast receiver.

Comment: but in general I think starting an activity from the outside of UI is considered not a good idea.  BTW, dialogs can pop up without starting a new activity.  But it general its not good to go from background to foreground without user interaction.

Comment: I think the most confusing part of your answer is what you find to be the most confusing part about my question. According the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html), "You don't need to develop your own provider if you don't intend to share your data with other applications." Which leaves me with the impression that ContentProviders are available to other applications trivially (editing the application manifest, perhaps, but I haven't looked into it).

Comment: I can get a context via the 'getContext()' method of ContentProvider, so having a context isn't an issue. I suppose I am going about this all wrong though, perhaps it *is* the applications job to make sure the user is logged in.